# Which address should I give my registrar NS or SOA?

Tags: hosting, amazon-web-services, domain-registration

I'm hosting my apps in amazon ec2 server and using route 53 for hosted zone, I created a Hosted Zone for my domain. I'm wondering which addresses should I provide to my registrar, NS or SOA for primary and secondary DNS?

Comment: You should clarify your question.  It sounds like you are asking about what information to give you registrar in order to use the DNS being hosted by your Amazon EC2 virtual server.  If that is the case, you will need to give them name server names and addresses that point to your DNS server hosted in the Amazon cloud.

Answer (score 1):

The registry will need the nameservers for your domain and possibly the addresses for those nameservers.

If your domain is `example.com`, you will need to supply the registrar with the `NS` records for `example.com`.

If any of the host-names given for the name-servers are under the `example.com` domain, e.g. `ns1.example.com`, you will need to supply the addresses of them separately, often called *glue records* or *host records* by the registrar.

You do *not* need to supply `SOA` records, since this record type is meant to be answered by authoritative servers, which does not include the registry.